# Android AsyncTask's onProgressUpdate not working

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, progress-bar

I have an `AsyncTask` in a class. I want it to display the progress while it is getting executed. But it is not printing the Logs.

```
private void registerBackground() {
    new AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String>() {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            Log.v("TAGGG", "IN doInBackground");
            msg = "Error: ";

            return msg;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(progress);
            Log.v("TAGGG", "Progress: " + progress[0] + "%");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String msg)
        {
            Log.v("TAGGG", msg);
        }
    }.execute();
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to use the publishProgress() method: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#publishProgress(Progress...)

> This method can be invoked from doInBackground(Params...) to publish
>   updates on the UI thread while the background computation is still
>   running. Each call to this method will trigger the execution of
>   onProgressUpdate(Progress...) on the UI thread.
>   onProgressUpdate(Progress...) will note be called if the task has been
>   canceled.

```
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Log.v("TAGGG", "IN doInBackground");
        msg = "Error: ";
        int i = 0;
        while (i <= 50) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(50);
                publishProgress(i);
                i++;
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                Log.i(TAGGG, e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        return msg;
    }
```

Comment: Why that `while` code? And Why `sleep` ? Won't it make it slow?

Comment: @micro.pravi the objective in an Asynctask is to simulate a long thread (downloading data, parsing a huge file) and displaying progress to the user.. The sleep is not meant to be on a production code!